# something wrong with cassandra memtable flush

Tags: cassandra

cassandra 3.0 refer document.
there are two ways to flush memtable.
one is memtable_heap,
another is commit log I see this in document. 
memtable_heap_space_in_mb Triggers a flush based on memtable_cleanup_threshold.

1.so exceed the value of memtable_heap_space_in_mb*memtable_cleanup_threshold will flush memtable,not just memtable_heap_space vlaue. is that right?

2.memtable_cleanup_threshold (Default: 0.11 1/(memtable_flush_writers + 1))note memtable_cleanup_threshold default value is 0.11 but also says value=1/(memtable_flush_writers + 1) the default value of memtable_flush_writers is 1. so memtable_cleanup_threshold should be 0.5,not 0.11 I do confuse about this.

3.how can query the actual value of these arguments?

4.How often flush  is better? I inserted 10M records into DB. but the insert rate cannot be stable.
I think something wrong with the membtable config.
how can i tune the config.
[click to view insert info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFv0J.png)

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with memtable flushing? It doesn't block writes or anything anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.you are right,seems that not membtable flushing problem.I guess that it is the cluster capacity limitation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.you are right,seems that not membtable flushing problem.I guess that it is the cluster capacity limitation.there is only 8G memory,and 4 core cpu.so set MAX_HEAP_SIZE:2G
HEAP_NEWSIZE:400M ,refer this document [https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html].I think the issue may be with this config.on the other hand,i confuse about the behavior of cassandra.I think he should more smart to receive request that he can control,instead of blocking and waiting.